# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: java, android-studio

Muy buenas:
estoy desarrollando una app que debe enviar un email a una cuenta de contacto.He intentado hacer como lo ponia en internet pero no consigo que me funcione,ademas cuando lo ejecuto, la app no me falla pero tampoco hace lo que necesito.
el codigo es el siguiente:

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy= new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();


StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
// Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
String to = "email_al_que_envio@gmail.com";

// Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
String from = "email_que_envia@gmail.com";

// Get system properties
Properties properties = System.getProperties();

// Setup mail server
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
properties.setProperty("mail.user", "mi_user");
properties.setProperty("mail.password", "mi_pass");

// Get the default Session object.
Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
           return new PasswordAuthentication("mi_user", "mi_pass");
      }
});

try {
     // Create a default MimeMessage object.
     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

     // Set From: header field of the header.
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

     // Set To: header field of the header.
     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

     // Set Subject: header field
     message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

     // Now set the actual message
     message.setText("This is actual message");

     // Send message
     Transport.send(message);
     Log.d("exito","exito");
} catch (MessagingException mex) {
     mex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Este código corre en la app o en el servidor.

Comment: el codigo corre en la app

Comment: Me parece que tendrías que repensar la app para que le pida al servidor enviar un emial en todo caso, como para controlar centralizadamente esos envíos. Al incluir direccion de correo, usuario, y password en el código de la app, perimero haces fácil que te hackeen e incluso te quiten la cuenta de correo o la usen para spam, segundo si cambias la dirección de correo o la clave se te hace imposible replicar eso a las apps ya instaladas (depende del usuario hacer el update), y tercero si usas cuentas de gmail probablemente estes violando alguno de los términos y condiciones del servicio.

Answer (score 0):

para ser un problema de certificados SSL que no le esta autentificando por no encontrar la ruta del certificado.

1) Podrías crear una llave publica para el certificado , tiene que instalar el openssl en tu maquina. Descargar el jar  bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar de  https://www.bouncycastle.org/ .

```
#!/bin/bash

 if [ -z $1 ]; then
  echo "Usage: cert2Android<CA cert PEM file>"
exit 1
 fi

 CACERT=$1
BCJAR=bcprov-jdk16-1.46.jar

TRUSTSTORE=mytruststore.bks
   ALIAS=`openssl x509 -inform PEM -subject_hash -noout -in $CACERT`

  if [ -f $TRUSTSTORE ]; then
    rm $TRUSTSTORE || exit 1
  fi

echo "Adding certificate to $TRUSTSTORE..."
  keytool -import -v -trustcacerts -alias $ALIAS \
       -file $CACERT \
         -keystore $TRUSTSTORE -storetype BKS \
        -providerclass org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider \
        -providerpath $BCJAR \
        -storepass secret

  echo "" 
  echo "Added '$CACERT' with alias '$ALIAS' to $TRUSTSTORE..."
```

2) Copiar el archivo  truststore mytruststore.bks en res/raw de la ruta del trustore de tu proyecto.

3) configura el contexto SSL de  la conexion.

.............
okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
try {
    KeyStore ksTrust = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
    InputStream instream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mytruststore);
    ksTrust.load(instream, "secret".toCharArray());

```
// TrustManager decides which certificate authorities to use.
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory
    .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(ksTrust);
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

okHttpClient.setSslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
   } catch (KeyStoreException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException |      CertificateException | KeyManagementException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
```

}
.................

Puedes encontrar mas informacion aqui : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047414/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-java-security-cert-certpathvalidatorexcepti

Comment: perdona pero me cuesta entender tu respuesta